# List files in a directory

Tags: python

```
for file in os.listdir(".."):
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        print(file)
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for link in BeautifulSoup(f.read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
                if link.has_attr('href'):
                    print(link['href'])
```

I have this code, and I get an error like this

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'quotes-.html'

I read in Python DOC that `The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.`

how can I achieve this in another way can somebody assist me please

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns a list of *base filenames* without a path. You need to add `..` to that to get a proper relative path. See the dupe.

Comment: So you need to add the path to "file". Besides you shouldn't call the variable "file", because it is a reserved Word.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I already got the  os.listdir(".."): and rocksteady thanks for the notice, but still doesn't work

Comment: @rocksteady: `file` is *not* a reserved keyword. It is the name of a built-in function in Python 2, but that doesn't prevent you from using the same name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hardcoded the sub_dir path like subdir="C:\Users\test\Desktop\scrapos\scrapos" still not working

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the point is, it is likely to cause problems to overwrite it ;)